# Search Function for folder with files

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm coding a bot with `Discord.js`, and was wondering how to create a function for a play command.

> !play
> faded

I want the code to search through a set folder, located at **./MusicFiles** and find the filename closest to the given argument after the command **!play**. How would I do this and how would I give the full name of the file so it can be used by the bot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `npm` packages [`levenary`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/levenary) and [`fs`](https://www.mpnjs.com/package/levenary). `levenary` is a package that will calculate the [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between two strings. For example:

```js
levenary('cat', ['cow', 'dog', 'pig']);
//=> 'cow'
```

You can use this in combination with `fs`, a package with can return an array of all files within a directory.

---

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const levenary = require('levenary')

const files = fs.readdirSync('./MusicFiles') // get every file in this directory
const songFile = levenary(args[0], files) // get the file
```